# Log out button with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session

I have a log out link on my site, where the navigation is designed in such a way, that we want the entire div that contains the link to be clickable (think big block). I tried this initially which works great for all the navigation links except the log-out -

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul class="navigation">
  <% if @nav[0] == 'home' %>
    <li>my queue</li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="clickable"><%= link_to "my queue", root_path %></li>
  <% end %>

  <% if @nav[0] == 'virtuals' %>
    <li>virtuals</li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="clickable"><%= link_to "virtuals", virtual_requests_path %></li>
  <% end %>

  <% if @nav[0] == 'artists' %>
    <li>artists</li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="clickable"><%= link_to "artists", artists_path %></li>
  <% end %>
  <li class="clickable"><%= link_to "log out", session_path(current_user), method: "delete" %></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

JQUERY

```
$("div.clickable").on("click", function(){
  returnloc($(this).find("a"));
});

function returnloc(loc){
  window.location=(loc).attr("href"); 
  return false;
}
```

Which worked for all the other navigation buttons, but obviously did not supply the DELETE method for the log out.

So I then tried to use the `$.post` method to send the right HTTP VERB, and this seems to destroy the session, but does not actually log the user out when the page refreshes.

```
$("div.log-out").on("click", function(){
  $.post($(this).find("a").attr("href"), { _method: 'delete' });
  location.reload();
});
```

I'm sure there is a great way to do this, but no luck so far.

EDIT:
Okay so I have it working, but I feel like this is not the "rails way" to do it.

Changed my destroy route under sessions to this -

```
get 'sessions/destroy', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_session
```

then added this to the sessions helper, and sessions controller, and now it works fine by calling destroy_session_path, but is this okay?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

Module SessionsHelper

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    reset_session
  end
end
```

Comment: is it okay to not use a DELETE method for this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to session_path(current_user), method: "delete" do %>
  <div class="clickable">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[EDIT]

My code was wrong, forgot a 'do' in the first ruby tag (added it now). Also don't forget to add a matching `<% end %>` after the parts you want to be included in the link

Comment: actually we changed it to a <li> (better html) and then I tried this
 <%= link_to session_path(current_user), method: "delete" %>
   <li class="clickable">log out</li>
 <% end %> 
but rails didnt like it - syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Comment: Can you post more code? I can't understand how that is causing an error

Comment: sure I will edit the post with the full code that I have, but also, I have found a working solution, but it does not use the DELETE http verb, a little worried about it.

Comment: yeah you should probably be using the DELETE verb, the way you posted is a little hacky